# How to select one drop down menu when multiple drop down have same id, class, href only innerHTML text is different

Tags: html

```
<div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-top-collapse">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Find a Doctor </a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Online Services </a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" rel="nofollow"> About Us </a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
</li>
</ul>
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 d-none d-sm-block">
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

I want to select dropdown which has text "find a Doctor". But it show me multiple list of dropdrown that's why I'm not be able to select one.

Here is my code

driver.findElement(By.name(" Find a Doctor ")).click();

And I also tried this code

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbarSupportedContent']/ul/li/a"));

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).

So it's wrong that alle dropdown lists have the same id.